# Verifying De Morgan's laws for two given fuzzy sets

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

How does one show graphically or otherwise that two fuzzy sets A and B with membership functions $1/(1+2x)$ and $1/\sqrt{1+2x}$ respectively, satisfy De Morgan's laws?

This is a question from Neural Fuzzy Systems by Chin-Teng Lin and C. S. George Lee.I was unable to find a solution to this.Could someone try to help me with this?

[Click to view graphs of the two membership functions with red and blue representing those of A,B respectively.
X axis represents x and Y axis,the membership function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkKmc.png)

Comment: As far as I know a membership function has to be between 0 and 1.

Comment: No put on hold as far as I am concerned. I like this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the univrse is $[0,\infty]$ because the membership function has to be between $0$ and $ 1$.

Since $$f_A=\frac1{1+2x}\leq f_B=\frac1{\sqrt{1+2x}},\ \text{ if } x\geq 0$$
we have that

$$f_{A\cup B}=\max(f_A,f_B)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+2x}}=f_{B}$$
and then

$$f_{\overline {A\cup B}}=1-f_B.$$

Then $f_{\overline A}=1-f_A$ and $f_{\overline B}=1-f_B$. So $f_{\overline A}\geq f_{\overline B}$ and $$f_{\overline A\cap\overline B}=\min(f_{\overline A},f_{\overline B})=f_{\overline B}=1-f_B.$$

That is,
$$f_{\overline {A\cup B}}=f_{\overline A\cap\overline B}$$
according to De Morgan's law.

Comment: Guess this works,but just curious..is it possible to do the same graphically?I have done similar questions,but the graphs were all linear then and hence it was pretty easy.Is there any difference in the method for non linear membership functions?As in this case.

Comment: The linearity / nonlinearity have nothing to di with the specific result.